# Problems controlling CheckBox

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make it so when a checkBox is checked, all other checkBox's become unchecked. I know there are some other ways to do it, but how would I go about it this way? Also, if the user is trying to uncheck the box currently checked, it should remain checked.

```
private void checkState(CheckBox b)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < cb.Count; i++)
            {
                if (cb[i] != b)
                {
                    cb[i].Checked = false;
                }
                //else
                //{
                //    cb[i].Checked = true;
                //}
            }

            b.Checked = true;

        }
```

Comment: What abouit using a RadioButton? Is it a requirement to use a checkbox?

Answer (score 2):

For this behaviour, you should use a `RadioButton` (a group of them) instead of checkbox, since it's their natural behaviour.

References:

[Radio Button - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/sytem.windows.forms.radiobutton%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771615%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

**Update**: if you still want to do it with `checkbutton` even against our advice, you could do something like this:

1º Create a function to modify the group of controls. Check if they're being changed. If not, they need to be uncheked

```
Private Sub modify(ByVal sender As CheckBox)

    For Each item As CheckBox In Me.Controls

        If (item.Equals(sender) = False) Then
            item.Checked = False
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

**Notice**: since I wrote it in VB, notice than `Me` means the actual form, and is replaced by `this` in C#. Anyway, you should put there the parent control of your group of `checkbox`.

2º Call this function in the **`click` event** of each checkbox. I would prefer `click` instead of `CheckedChanged` to don't force a second call to the function recursively.

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    modify(sender)
End Sub
```

Comment: I've tried them in the past and it didn't work well for the task at hand. Is there a way to do it with checkboxes?

Comment: Why didn't they work? Of couse you can get all the `checkbox` inside your parent control, check if they're the one you're changing, and if it's not you can change its value. Will update the answer in a while.

Comment: _Is there a way to do it with checkboxes?_ Of course, but not without surprising the users. So it would be a mistake. You can have alist of the checkboxes and uncheck everyone but sender, but as I said: It'll be non-standard behaviour..

Comment: What is special for the task at hand? all you need to do is to put those radiobutton that shall exclude each other in one group, maybe a groupbox, so the user can easily see they belong together..

Comment: This answer is a) in VB, the question asks explicitly for C# and b) smells a little of an endless loop (not sure, though, pardon me if I'm wrong) and c) goes over all controls in Me.Controls, instead of the array or list of checkboxes `cb` the OP supplies..

Comment: @TaW ops, that's true, I made it in VB.NET, my mistake. Since I advice to use `click` event it won't be a infinite loop =). About the controls, It would only go for all the `checkbox` in the form, since other kind of controls couldn't be cast to checkbox.

Comment: Yes, but the code is using CheckedChanged and there may well be CheckBoxes that are not supposed to be in the 'group'. But he shouldn't do it anyway, or tell us more about the actual reasoning..

Comment: The code is an example, and I told him to use the function at `click` event instead. And to change it to his group, he just have to change `Me` (what, by the way, doesn't exist in C#, but `this`) to his group container, whatever it is.